# Unicode / emojis in Github markdown

Tags: github, unicode, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I just made a failed attempt to put unicode in Github markdown (in a README.md file) in my project.

I tried this:

```
(U+262E)
```

but it was not interpreted as unicode. Is there a way to put unicode characters in Github markdown?

Comment: Just type or paste them in unescaped form?

Comment: which looks like?? thx

Comment: Like? You just have a unicode code and don't know what it is? Weird.. but okay, just google the code.

Comment: @AlexanderMills like this ☮

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I believe the correct answer is to use unicode characters of the following (decimal) form

```
&#9658;
&#767;
&#2400;
```

the above become:

►
˿
ॠ

Try it for yourself on Github and see. You have to paste the raw character strings, not the unicode symbol itself. It's **not** about what shows up in your editor, it's what actually displays on github.com.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm using Vim to save a utf8 document, and Chrome, or Calibre's epub reader, to view the resulting .markdown file. The unicode character `&#00c7;` (c-cedilla) shows up as `fa�c7;ade`

Comment: @JonathanHartley look on Github, not through your editor(s), each markdown interpreter is slightly different

Comment: Ah, right, thanks. I didn't spot that this question was specifically about rendering in github. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: if it works for you on github I'd appreciate an upvote :)

Comment: Although I wish this answer would be the correct one (upvoted), many symbols do not seem to work for me on Github (checking on the Wiki markdown) - for example 25C4 is not working like this, it only works when pasted. Taking symbols from http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/25A0-25FF

Comment: @DannyB you must use the decimal value. _&#9668;_

Comment: You can specify and HTML character entity, like "&amp;" or "&lpar;". You can specify any Unicode character using the hex formulation, like "&#x2713;" or the decimal formulation, like "&#10003;".

Comment: Thank you, Alexander, I can now use emoji in our Markdown-powered wiki.

Comment: The hexadecimal form works as well. You just need to use the &#x.... form. E.g. &#x00c7

Answer (score 17):

You can use either decimal or hex code point or HTML entity name (if exists) of a unicode character:

```
&#8364; &#x20AC; &euro;
```

displays as

€ € €

Answer (score 13):

There's no special syntax, just use the character directly... ☮.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, I believe my answer is more correct.

Comment: What is the implied encoding? Can you explicitly override it?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm using Vim to save a utf .md document, and Chrome (or Calibre's epub reader) to view it. In both cases the pasted character appears as something else. I presume the encoding assumed by the reading applications is not the utf-8 used by vim when it saves the document.

Comment: @JonathanHartley you can see what encoding vim is using by typing  _:set encoding_ when the file is open.

Comment: You should really use UTF-8 encoding for all Unicode text.

Answer (score 3):

If unicode symbols are required in the code block in Github, then instead of using ``` block use `<pre>` block.

Replace

````
```
Some text: &#x2718;
Some text: &#x2713;
```
````

With

```
<pre>
Some text: &#x2718;
Some text: &#x2713;
</pre
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the complete answer that OP was asking for, but in case you want emojis for GitHub purposes there is [a gist here](https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/7360908) outlining how to input them. The basic idea is just that you would input `:smile:` into your markdown and that would produce a smiley face. Other commands are listed in the gist

Answer (score 1):

If your editor saves text files in utf8 encoding with a BOM byte-order-mark, then unicode characters that you cut-and-paste seem to be rendered OK.

Comment: Github's web editor is one such editor.

Answer (score 1):

Using visual studio code Ver.1.62.2, `&alpha; &beta; &Alpha; &Beta;` was correctly rendered in markdown preview window.