# How do I show the "up" and "down" arrow keyboard key in GitHub markdown?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

How do I show the "up" and "down" arrow keyboard keys (←, ↑, → and ↓) in GitHub markdown? So far I am able to show <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd>. But how do I show the arrow symbol instead the text "up" and "down"?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Unicode in Github markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36616878/6309)", you need to  use the decimal value of the characters you want.

In your case, the [arrow symbols](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrows-symbols/), as [shown here](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/arrows/):

- [left arrow](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2190/index.htm): ← `&#8592;`
- [upward arrow](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2191/index.htm): ↑ `&#8593;`
- [right arrow](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2191/index.htm): → `&#8594;`
- [downward arrow](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2191/index.htm): ↓ `&#8595;`

Comment: Thank you for also providing the [link](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/math/) to the library of unicode that can be used for github markdown. :)

Comment: @SunBear Yes, I find that reference for HTML Symbols quite complete.

Answer (score 44):

You can use *unicode arrows*. It works nicely everywhere (it has worked in all markdown readers I have tried).

Here is a sample. Simple: ***copy and paste** the ones you like in your text!* :
← → ↑ ↓
↔ ↕
↖ ↗ ↘ ↙
⤡ ⤢
↚ ↛ ↮
⟵ ⟶ ⟷
⇦ ⇨ ⇧ ⇩
⬄ ⇳
⬁ ⬀ ⬂ ⬃
⬅  ⮕ ➡  ⬆ ⬇
⬉ ⬈ ⬊ ⬋
⬌ ⬍
   
   
 
⭠ ⭢ ⭡ ⭣
⭤ ⭥
⭦ ⭧ ⭨ ⭩

([other unicode arraws](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html))

Answer (score 22):

You can also use `&uarr;`↑, `&darr;`↓, `&larr;`←, `&rarr;`→ to create the arrows. The first letter is the direction of the arrow.
Also `&harr;`↔ gives you a double headed arrow (right/left)
So you could do `<kbd>&uarr;</kbd>` <kbd>↑</kbd>

Comment: This is a lot easier to remember and type out than the other answers :)

Answer (score 8):

Another way is to use [Emojis](https://help.github.com/articles/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax/#using-emoji).

- `:arrow_up:` [image: U+2B06]
- `:arrow_down:` [image: U+2B07]
- `:arrow_left:` [image: U+2B05]
- `:arrow_right:` [image: U+27A1]

There are some [art of Unicode](https://github.com/ikatyang/emoji-cheat-sheet/blob/master/README.md), for example `:arrow_double_up:` `:arrow_upper_left:` `:arrow_up_down:`.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me this alternative approach.

Answer (score 3):

The arrow can be shown as:-

1. Up arrow:- `&uarr;`
2. Down arrow:- `&darr;`
3. Left arrow:- `&larr;`
4. Right arrow:- `&rarr;`
5. Double-headed arrow:- `&harr;`

Answer (score 1):

https://unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_2190.html This link may be helpful.

```
2190     ←  LEFTWARDS ARROW
        →   20EA ◌⃪ combining leftwards arrow overlay
2191     ↑  UPWARDS ARROW
        •   IPA: egressive airflow
2192     →  RIGHTWARDS ARROW
        =   z notation total function
2193     ↓  DOWNWARDS ARROW
        •   IPA: ingressive airflow
```