# Greek text in markdown or md

Tags: markdown

I would like to write a few greek paragraphs in markdown or md file using a freeware editor such as Mdcharm etc. Is it possible and what exact headers I have to use?

A sample and complete example would help me a lot!

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unicode in Github markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538879/unicode-in-github-markdown)

Comment: @UNOPARATOR, this isn't about GitHub Markdown.

Comment: OP, you can probably just use Unicode. How would you type Greek characters normally?

Comment: @Chris, markdown is markdown. I don't think it matters if it is Github or not. **asimkon**, please try converting your Greek characters (unicode characters) to the decimal form (**Ϋ --> &#939;**), and let us know the outcome. You might use this [link](https://unicodelookup.com/#greek) as a guide.

Comment: Not true, @UNOPARATOR. There are many variations and extensions to Markdown. GitHub supports some of them. Other processors and tools support others. But I misread the suggested duplicate; it likely applies here too.

Comment: As @Chris states, just use Unicode and ensure the file is saved as UTF-8. Most any Markdown implementations should handle it just fine.